# What support does MS Access 2007 and newer have for concurrent operations?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office, ms-access-2010

I want to create a small DB for recording test results. Under normal circumstances, Access would be easily capable enough but I do not know if it supports concurrent connections - in the old pre-2007 versions I'm sure it used to be very limited.

Anticipated usage might be 10 network PCs with connections to the DB, each making 1 query a second - and that's probably an exaggeration. Is this well within the reasonable capabilities of an ACCDB database?

Comment: Are you not satisfied with the answer below? Do you need more details?

Comment: @Invent-Animate thanks for the reminder - see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some information put out [by Microsoft a long time ago](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811092.aspx) and [Here for Access 2010 Explicitly](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

- No SMP support
- Maximum of 255 users, but recommended for up to 20 total users.
- 2 GB of data
- No transaction logging

I have also heard/seen this everywhere - "According to Microsoft: A maximum of 64 connections per process with a limit of 256 concurrent open read/write connections per database.", but I cannot find the source.

When you say "each making one query a second" .. I am assuming these are `SELECT` statements? Or `UPDATE` statements, or a mixture of both?

The architecture you're describing spawned this idea of having a Back End database that stores all of the tables with data, and multiple Front Ends (distributed and used by your users) which have these tables linked and that's how the users interact with them. If this architecture isn't adopted - there will be issues with, but not limited to: corruption, record locking, and possible data-mismatch because of all the concurrent updating.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your last paragraph. It seems to suggest Access _isn't_ multi-connection-safe, concurrent updates will break, non-atomicity, etc? Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Mr.Boy If the same set of users use the *same* database, this can be the scenario. If you utilize the split-database architecture, and each user has their own front end - it is safe.

Comment: Isn't being able to support concurrent users doing things at once pretty much the _definition_ of a database that's useful for multiple users? If the DB can't handle two `update` commands from different connections at the same time, what use is it?

Comment: @Mr.Boy Well, then we get into [RecordLocks](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/RecordLocks-Property-6ca29bbb-8824-4671-8087-97fe0568019a).. I didn't develop Access - this is just my understanding of the software and the things I have learned while developing in it. The different architectures are discussed [here](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74) by Microsoft

Comment: I just realised, you're talking about Front End Access forms, etc? I only mean to use Access as a back-end... our software would talk to the DB directly with raw SQL.

Answer (score -1):

If you try 2 concurrent users with a fairly complex application - like a pos software - that requires in one routine reading, inserting, updating several times, you will get error prompts like the database is being locked by another user.

The program slows down significantly under such concurrent user stress; otherwise I think msaccess is great.

The claim by MS that msaccess is capable of numerous concurrent users has cost many programmers countless lost hours in coding for a shared msaccess database only to find out that it is one big lie.

Another thing with Ms Access on win 7 and 8 is that it can hangs up the program so badly at times and Microsoft support could not troubleshoot the problem until one great user posted the registry-tweak solution online.

Another serious bug in some versions of windows 7 & 8 is IF your database is stored in your application directory under program files or program files (x86) you may end up having the records reverted to original after days or even months after usage.  This would be hellish experience not just for the programmer and also end-users. Days, weeks or even months of data completely gone.  I have read of this doomsday experience online. So you must ensure the database is moved to another location. Microsoft expect everyone to know about this or you pay for it dearly. Very responsible company, you know.

Of course you can go for mssql but then again be warned there is '-2147217871 ODBC server timeout' bug of over a decade that hangs not just the application but the computer for minutes so completely that it seems everything stops.  This happens if your program is complex like a pos software requiring multiple reading and inserting and updating.

It had been confirmed by Microsoft at one of its site - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx#Y0 - as a bug in MsSql that has yet to be resolved.   That page content however has now been changed probably it is too much of an embarrassment for MS.  A MS support staff-member once wrote there: "We will look into this bug in future."  How nice.

Many businesses depends on Ms Access database but the way things are going someone better come up with a compatible database without code change on the program side.  This is badly needed by the programming community.

I spent 10 years writing a pos software using msaccess and mssql only to be screwed up by Microsoft on these issues time and again. It comes as surprise even to me that such an established company can be so sloppy and irresponsible on such critical products namely msaccess and mssql databases.

Now I only use msaccess database for a single user.  As one knowledgeable developer once wrote: "the number of concurrent users for msaccess is actually 1, repeat one." Period.